# ActionScript 3 EventListener and Function with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

So I'm working on a project in Adobe Animate, it's an interactive map.

What I'm trying to do is have a popup fade in when I mouse-over key areas. For example, a popup that explains what can go into recycling in the recycling area. Since there are multiple recycling locations, I created two functions, one to hide the popup and another to show it, and am using a switch case to determine which recycling location is having the mouse over event occur.

So, for example, the show event is set up like this:

```
function showShred(event: MouseEvent, shredNum: int): void {
switch (shredNum) {
    case 1:
        TransitionManager.start(shreddingInfo_flr3_1, {
            type: Fade,
            direction: Transition.IN,
            duration: 3,
            easing: Strong.easeOut
        });
        break;
    case 2:
        TransitionManager.start(shreddingInfo_flr3_2, {
            type: Fade,
            direction: Transition.IN,
            duration: 3,
            easing: Strong.easeOut
        });
        break;
    case 3:
        TransitionManager.start(shreddingInfo_flr3_3, {
            type: Fade,
            direction: Transition.IN,
            duration: 3,
            easing: Strong.easeOut
        });
        break;
}
}
```

So I was adding the event listeners and they're just causing errors and don't seem to like that the function takes a parameter.

```
shredBtn_Flr3_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, showShred(1));
```

I'm quite unfamiliar with ActionScript 3.0 so any help and tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error #1: Event handler takes the only parameter: the event object.

Error #2: You are to subscribe a method to the event, **showShred(1)** calls the method immediately and returns **null**, which is not a valid event handler.

Event object contains the reference to the source of the event. In your case you can do it in the following way:

```
shredBtn_Flr3_1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, showShred);
shredBtn_Flr3_2.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, showShred);
shredBtn_Flr3_3.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, showShred);

function showShred(e:MouseEvent): void
{
    switch (e.currentTarget)
    {
        case shredBtn_Flr3_1:
            fadeIn(shreddingInfo_flr3_1);
            break;

        case shredBtn_Flr3_2:
            fadeIn(shreddingInfo_flr3_2);
            break;

        case shredBtn_Flr3_3:
            fadeIn(shreddingInfo_flr3_3);
            break;
    }
}

function fadeIn(target:DisplayObject):void
{
    TransitionManager.start(target, {
        type: Fade,
        direction: Transition.IN,
        duration: 3,
        easing: Strong.easeOut
    });
}
```